# isBodyHtml is true and AlternateViews set, still no View Code option in Outlook 2010 using c#

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2010, system.net.mail

I have both `.isBodyHtml=true` and `AlternativeViews` option with one for `text/html`, but the `View Code` option in Outlook is *still* grayed out and not available for me to use.

My code:

```
var emailContent = "<html><body><b>this should be bold</b></body></html>";
var client = new SmtpClient("...", 25)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("...", "..."),
    EnableSsl = true
};
var msg = new MailMessage("...", toEmail, "subject", emailContent);
msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(emailContent, new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html")));
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
client.Send(msg);
```

Note: I am using GMail's smtp, so I wonder if GMail is doing something to the headers saying, "hey, no one should be able to View Source in Outlook for gmail emails"? Thanks!

**Edit:** screenshot of grayed out View Code button in Outlook 2010: [image]

Comment: If the email is showing with all the proper HTML, even if you can't see the source, this is more likely an Outlook issue than an C# issue.  Can you include a screenshot of the grayed out option?

Comment: Please see edit w/ screenshot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want is actually the `View Source` command, not the `View Code` one.  This is available by default under `Message -> Move -> Actions -> Other Actions -> View Source`.

[image: View Source location]